# Get data from firebase realtime database in android

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pojo

I am trying to get data from firebase realtime database in android. I have created a json data file and imported the json file in firebase database. The data file looks like this :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
        "name" : "one",
        "age" : "ten"
        },{
        "name" : "two",
        "age" : "twenty"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created a POJO class. Now how can I get all the json objects from the array? I've searched for a while but can't understand what will be the reference & child here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend changing your Firebase structure as following:

- replace [] with {} as Firebase recommends using this practice
- add a specific unique id for every user(or item) you have in `data` node.

Take this example:

[image]

As you can see in the picture every user has a specific id. Firebase provides for every user an unique id which you can get with `String userId= user.getUid();`.

You can create unique ids aswell and get them using `String key = Database.child("users").push().getKey();` (not advised to be used for user ids)

If you wish to read the data you structured I recommend reading [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Also read [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: Thanks! But one thing - if I replace "[]" with "{}" , will it be a valid json? https://jsonlint.com/ showing error if I do this.

Comment: As I said, using {} instead of [] is recommended when structuring your firebase database. If you choose to import the structure from a json provider you might get errors as you stated. Is it required for you to import the database structure? If no, you can create your structure from Android Studio by adding nodes with specific keys and children to those nodes.(known as mapping)

Answer (score 1):

When you said `val fireDataBaseRef FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("data")` you are holding a reference of your root tree. with this reference you can `fireDataBaseRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener)`

where

```
val childEventListener: ChildEventListener = object : ChildEventListener {

        override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError?) {}

        override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {}

        override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {

        }

        override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {
            // childs added
        }

        override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {

        }
    }
```

just put some logs in the overrided functions and you will see the action